# multipeer Connectivity using H264 encoding and decoding?

Tags: swift3, xcode8, h.264, multipeer-connectivity

MultiPeer connectivity for Live Video Streaming between Phones that are connected.Which i have Done the streaming using this but the streaming is very slow and Quality of the Video is very low. So Decided to Add H264 encoding and decoding method. How can we Implement this Method using Peer to Peer.

My Question is "Is it Possible to encode and decode the video and Stream through MultiPeer connectivity which the Devices we are connected?"

I have used this Links for H264 And Multipeer Connectivity

**H264 which is in objective-C i converted the code to Swift.**
https://mobisoftinfotech.com/resources/mguide/h264-encode-decode-using-videotoolbox/

**MultiPeerConnectivity which is in objective-C i converted the code to Swift**

https://github.com/pj4533/AVCaptureMultipeerVideoDataOutput

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: @Hawk I don't find any solution with H264 encoding and decoding regarding this multipeerConnectivity. But I have done this multipeerConnectivity using WebRTc. https://github.com/Mahabali/BonjourWebrtc

Comment: Any chance you solved it with built-in methods? @Sreejiths